# Programmatically added checkbox doesnt save state

Tags: android, checkbox

In my code i have a couple of views in my linearlayout. Views adds programmatically

```
mUserProfile = mNavigationCallback.getUserProfile();
    List<Contact> contacts = mUserProfile.getContacts();
    for (Contact c : contacts) {
        View view = View.inflate(getActivity(), R.layout.item_contact, null);
        TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvPhone);
        tv.setText(c.getValue());
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.cbContactChecked);
        cb.setId(generateViewId());
        if (c.getType().equals("email")) {
            llEmailContacts.addView(view);
        }
        if (c.getType().equals("phone")) {
            llPhoneContacts.addView(view);
        }
    }
```

Each view contains linear layout with Textview and Checkbox.
But checkbox doesn't save his own state when screen rotating, whats problem and how to fix it?

UPD: I cant use onSaveInstanceState, because this fragment using setRetainInstance(true)

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange

Comment: Are you aware that default behavior when rotating Android causes all data to be reset? You need to handle saving of state in onSaveInstanceState() and retrieve it either in onCreate() or onRestoreInstanceState()

Comment: also please thoroughly go through an activity life cycle. whenever your device orientation changes, onCreate() is called again !! So that means your UI will lose its state. Please consider using fragments

Comment: What state are you expecting to have saved? How are you creating the widgets in the new activity/fragment with the same widget IDs as you had in the old activity/fragment?

Comment: @CommonsWare I'm just want to save checked states. It's works pretty for xml defined checkboxes, but doesnt work for dynamically added. And I cant use saveInstanceState because fragment using setRetain(true). 
Id's generating with generateViewId() method from View class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Id's generating with generateViewId() method from View class

That may be fine for the initial time you set up the widgets. For the second and subsequent times, you will need to use **the same IDs that you used before** if you expect the built-in saved instance state logic to work.

Comment: Thank you, i have solved my problem. See my answer and correct if smth wrong.

Answer (score 0):

When you are rotating your screen your activity gets destroyed and restored again. All member variables are recreated and all views are redrawn. You can add some flags to manifest, but you should consider saving state in method `onSaveInstancestate()`

In your example, Contact could have a variable `isSelected` which changes on checkbox selection

```
mUserProfile = mNavigationCallback.getUserProfile();
    List<Contact> contacts = mUserProfile.getContacts();
    for (Contact c : contacts) {
        View view = View.inflate(getActivity(), R.layout.item_contact, null);
        TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvPhone);
        tv.setText(c.getValue());
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.cbContactChecked);
        cb.setChecked(c.isSelected)
        cb.setId(generateViewId());
        if (c.getType().equals("email")) {
            llEmailContacts.addView(view);
        }
        if (c.getType().equals("phone")) {
            llPhoneContacts.addView(view);
        }
    }
```

Then you override `onSaveInstanceState` where you save all contacts

```
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundla outState) {
//Save your userprofile somehow, for example by serializing it using json
//and add to bundle
}
```

Then in onCreate()

```
public void onCreate(Bundle state) {
//Get your userProfile from state. If it is null, there was no state saved then get it like you //already do = mUserProfile = mNavigationCallback.getUserProfile();
List<Contact> contacts = mUserProfile.getContacts();
for (Contact c : contacts) {
            View view = View.inflate(getActivity(), R.layout.item_contact, null);
            TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvPhone);
            tv.setText(c.getValue());
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.cbContactChecked);
            cb.setChecked(c.isSelected)
            cb.setId(generateViewId());
            if (c.getType().equals("email")) {
                llEmailContacts.addView(view);
            }
            if (c.getType().equals("phone")) {
                llPhoneContacts.addView(view);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: I'm really want to use onSaveInstanceState callback, but bundle will be always empty because of setRetainInstance(true) method.
I've just want to understand why saving state works fine for all view added in xml with ID's, but doesnt work for dynamically added views and ID's

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by saving generated ID and re-using it:

```
 mUserProfile = mNavigationCallback.getUserProfile();
    List<Contact> contacts = mUserProfile.getContacts();
    for (Contact c : contacts) {
        View view = View.inflate(getActivity(), R.layout.item_contact, null);
        TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvPhone);
        tv.setText(c.getValue());
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.cbContactChecked);
        if (c.getViewId() == 0) {
            c.setViewId(generateViewId());
        }
        cb.setId(c.getViewId());

        cb.setTag(c);
        Timber.d("setting CB: " + "ID :" + cb.getId() + " tag " + cb.getTag());

        cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(mOnCheckedChangeListener);
        if (c.getType().equals("email")) {
            llEmailContacts.addView(view);
        }
        if (c.getType().equals("phone")) {
            llPhoneContacts.addView(view);
        }
    }
```